# Help with integral from Boltzmann equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have a function 
$$
g\left(x,v,t\right) = u\left(x,t\right)\cdot v + \theta\left(x,t\right)\frac{1}{2}\left(\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2 - 5\right)
$$
where $g(x,v,t),\theta(x,t)$ are scalars and $u(x,t), v\in \mathbb R^N,N=2,3$. I also have a matrix valued function $X=X(v)\in\mathbb R^{N\times N}$, satisfying
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N} X \xi \, \text{d}v = 0 \qquad\text{ if }\quad\xi = 1,v_1,v_2,v_3,\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2
$$
and I write for shorthand
$$
A := v\otimes v - \frac{1}{3} \left\lvert v\right\rvert^2 I
$$
Where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  I'm trying to verify the following integral identity:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N} X v\cdot\nabla_xg \, \text{d}v = \nu \left[ \nabla_x u + \left(\nabla_xu\right)^T - \frac{2}{3} \,\nabla\cdot u I \right]
$$
with proportionality constant $\nu = \int_{\mathbb R^N} X : A \ \text{d}v$.

For context this is the line on page 74 that starts "With (6.16) one easily finds that" in the following book chapter on the [Boltzmann equation and its hydrodynamic limits](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/golse/Surveys/FGHdBookEvEq.pdf). You might (rightly) guess that $\nu$ is the viscosity of the limiting solution which will solve the Navier-Stokes-Fourier system.

I'm honestly at a loss at how to arrive at the right hand side.
I can't get very far other than the first obvious step,

$$
\nabla_x g = \left(\nabla_x u\right)^T v + \nabla_x \theta\frac{1}{2}\left(\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2 - 5\right)
$$

My immediate issues:

1. how do I express the integral of the first term in a useful way?
2. I suspect the second integral should disappear, but this isn't obvious if I only assume the $L^2$ orthogonality conditions $\int_{\mathbb R^N} X \xi \, \text{d}v = 0 \;\text{ if }\;\xi = 1,v,\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2$ because of the extra $v$ in $v\cdot \nabla_x$.

I would be very happy with just a first step even, or a source for how to deal with these kinds of integrals (seems a bit too specific but I can hope!)

---

**(edit)**: Just in case it is useful, $X = \tilde A M_{1,0,1}$ where $M_{1,0,1}(v) = \dfrac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3/2}}\,\exp\left(\dfrac{\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2}{2}\right)$ is the 'Maxwellian velocity distribution', and $\tilde A$ is the unique solution $L^2(M\,\text{d}v)$-orthogonal to $\operatorname{span}\left(1,v_1,v_2,v_3,\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2\right)$ to the equation $\mathcal{L} \tilde A = A$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the linearization of the quadratic hard-sphere Boltzmann collision operator $Q$.

Just in case *this* is useful, I also type up the only useful looking computation I have:
\begin{align}
 \int X_{ij} v\cdot \nabla_x g \, \text{d}v 
&= \int X_{ij}\left[ v^lv^k \partial_{x^k}u^l + \partial{x^k} \theta v^k \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2 - 5\right)\right]\text{d}v \\
&= \int X_{ij}\left[\left(v\otimes v : \nabla_x u\right) + \nabla_x \theta \cdot \left(\dfrac{v\left\lvert v\right\rvert^2 - 5v}{2}\right)\right]  \text{d}v
\end{align}

Comment: @moonshine Sorry, it should be $\xi = 1,v_1,v_2,v_3,|v|^2$, and then the integral is interpreted component wise. I should have been more careful.

Comment: It bothers me that there is no $\theta$ term in the answer. Clearly the $5 v$ term will integrate away to zero, but there seems to be no ansatz that allows us to eliminate the $v{|v|}^2$ term. Incidentally, this whole thing is very reminiscent of the Irving-Kirkwood procedure. Edited to add: Symmetry should do it. There is no special directionality to the $X$ matrix, so its integral against any odd power of $v$ should disappear.

Comment: Assuming that we can eliminate the $\theta$ terms by symmetry, it looks to me like this whole thing reduces to $\partial_k u_{\ell} \int X_{ij} A_{\ell k} dv$, in which case perhaps some separation into diagonal terms and off diagonal terms might do it (taking advantage of the fact that $A$ is symmetric)? Also: Doesn't the 2/3 factor only happen when the dimensionality is 3?

Comment: Hi @JohnBarber, thanks for the comments. I'm not so sure I follow how to apply a symmetry argument because I know very little about $X$. As for the 2/3 factor, I think you are right but this is my first foray into this part of fluids so I'm not sure what its supposed to be. Thanks very much for the Irving-Kirkwood name-drop, I will read up on that in the time being and give the symmetry argument a bash :)